# How to set state.backend.rocksdb.localdir with code

Tags: apache-flink

I write and execute flink code in my local IDE using RocksDBStateBackend as the state backend.

The path specified in the RocksDBStateBackend's constructor is the path that is the checkpoint path that the local state data will be written into this path during checkpoint phrase.

There is an option `state.backend.rocksdb.localdir` that can be used to set the local rocksdb path,I would ask how to set this option with code, so that, I can specify the local storage path for the RocksDB state backend in my code,

`state.checkpoints.num-retained` is also another option that I want to set with code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```java
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.setString("state.backend", "rocksdb");
conf.setString("state.backend.rocksdb.localdir", "/tmp");
conf.setString("state.checkpoints.dir", "s3:///bucket/checkpoints");
conf.setString("execution.checkpointing.interval", "10s");
conf.setString("state.checkpoints.num-retained", "2");

StreamExecutionEnvironment env =
  StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(conf);
```

Comment: Thanks @david-anderson for the helpful answer，I tried ,and `conf.setString("state.checkpoints.num-retained", "2");` works for me. But, I am not sure localdir configuration works: `conf.setString("state.backend.rocksdb.localdir", "D:/flink-checkpoints/rocks-local");` When the application keeps runnging, there is nothing under this directoy, I am not sure if this works as expected.

Comment: The localdir is not where checkpoints go. Checkpoints are for recovery, and normally should go to a distributed file system, though for testing you might use a local directory. The rocksdb localdir, on the other hand, is for the ephemeral storage of the working state.

Comment: The localdir might be empty if your state is small enough to fit in memory. I believe, however, that during checkpointing the working state is flushed to the localdir.